# How to insert a new record into a table with hierarchyid

Tags: t-sql, hierarchyid

I’m learning how to deal with hierarchical data using hierarchyid. Have read a tutorial. The demo data is composed of precalculated hierarchyids. I’m familiar with parent/child tables using IDENTITY (1, 1) in the primary key. I understand that I must provide the value of the hierarchyid. But do not know how to do that. How can I obtain the value for the hierarchyid for a new record without parent and for a new record with a parent (given that I have the hierarchyid of the parent)? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1192607/Combination-of-Id-ParentId-and-HierarchyId

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft states it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15): "*It is up to the application to generate and assign HierarchyId values in such a way that the desired relationship between rows is reflected in the values*."

HierarchyId always has a parent, the top branches have a root as a parent.

Some examples with [GetDescendant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/getdescendant-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
declare @Parent hierarchyid = 0x; -- root
    
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1/', '/2/').ToString()     -- /1.1/
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1/', '/1.1/').ToString()   -- /1.0/
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1/', '/1.0/').ToString()   -- /1.-1/
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1/', '/1.-1/').ToString()  -- /1.-2/
    
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1.1/', '/2/').ToString()   -- /1.2/
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1.2/', '/2/').ToString()   -- /1.3/
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1.3/', '/2/').ToString()   -- /1.4/
    
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1.3/', '/1.4/').ToString() -- /1.3.1/
    
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8/', '/1.2.3.4.5.6.7.9/').ToString() -- /1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1/
    
    
-- by the way
    
declare @Hid hierarchyid = '/1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1/';
select @Hid; -- 0x63A08A49A85258
    
declare @Hid hierarchyid = '/-1.-2.-3.-4.-5.-6.-7.-8.-1234567890/';
select @Hid; -- 0x41F8F87A3C1D8E87216D9A81A73A
    
    
    -- special cases with null
    
print @Parent.GetDescendant(null, null).ToString()    -- /1/
print @Parent.GetDescendant('/1/', null).ToString()   -- /2/
print @Parent.GetDescendant(null, '/1/').ToString()   -- /0/
```

So, to generate a new HierarchyId for your new record, you have to take a parent (or root), use `GetDescendant` function and indicate after which child or between which two children you want to add it.